# How to set version number in Jenkins display build name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the Jenkins UI, I want my builds to display as **1.0.1-snapshot.134** rather than simply **#134**. I know I can do this:

```
currentBuild.displayName = "app-name-#" + currentBuild.number
```

But that only gives the build number, not the version. Looking at the docs, I didn't see the version attribute. How do I supply that? I calculate the version in the `environment` section like so:

```
// Build Version
MAJOR_MINOR_VERSION = "1.0.1-snapshot"
BUILD_VERSION = "${MAJOR_MINOR_VERSION}.${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Can I get this into the display name?

Comment: The version is a custom string that you are specifying and is extrinsic to Jenkins. Please add to the question how you are defining the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access variables in the `environment` directive from within keys in the `env` object in Groovy in the pipeline scope:

```
currentBuild.displayName = "app-name-#" + env.BUILD_VERSION
```

Comment: The displayName has to be set at the top of file. BUILD_VERSION is set afterwards, so the display name is printing out as "null-134".

Comment: Jenkins seems to have picked up the right version name now. Thanks a lot!